# Wildcard character for numbers similar to *

Tags: stata

In Stata, I can use `*` to represent any character. Is there a similar symbol for any number?

For example, I have `state_1`, `state_2`,..., `state 50`. However, I cannot use `state_*` to represent all these variables because I have another variable named `state_num`.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following toy example based on your variable names:

```
clear
set obs 1

forvalues i = 1 / 4 {
    generate _state_1`i' = .
}

generate _state_num = .

list, abbreviate(10)

     +------------------------------------------------------------+
     | _state_11   _state_12   _state_13   _state_14   _state_num |
     |------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |         .           .           .           .            . |
     +------------------------------------------------------------+
```

You can use `?` instead of `*`, which matches (any) single character:

```
list _state_??, abbreviate(10)

     +-----------------------------------------------+
     | _state_11   _state_12   _state_13   _state_14 |
     |-----------------------------------------------|
  1. |         .           .           .           . |
     +-----------------------------------------------+
```

Alternatives specific to numbers are typically only used in
certain commands or functions.

For example, `#` is used in the `rename group` command:

```
rename (*_#) (_#[2]*[1])

list, abbreviate(10)

     +------------------------------------------------------------+
     | _11_state   _12_state   _13_state   _14_state   _state_num |
     |------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |         .           .           .           .            . |
     +------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Functions for regular expressions such as `ustrregexm()` accept `0-9` or `\d`:

```
foreach var of varlist * {
    if ustrregexm("`var'", "[a-z_]+[0-9]+") display ustrregexs(0)
}

_state_11
_state_12
_state_13
_state_14
```